# Getting Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when i am integrating AWS to my code using pods

Tags: xcode, amazon-s3, cocoapods

As I create

```
[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey..]
```

I am getting error like as below.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSServiceConfiguration", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSServiceManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSStaticCredentialsProvider", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why?

Comment: Hello,

I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Have you installed using cococapods?

Comment: I have tried also cocoaPods and also without cocoaPods, I am going crazy all day looking and trying to solve this :(

Comment: When you have installed through cocoa-pods, have you seen any warnings on terminal?  After completion of install.

Comment: Yes, is said to add $(inherited) in other linker flags of my project. I added it and it doesn't help. I did pod update and it does not show anymore warnings.

Comment: Try again.    Just take fresh code then add that $(inherited) first and after that try install cocoappds.

Comment: I managed finally to run my project after transferring a few frameworks to Pod, AWS, Parse, Facebook, SDWebImage, MBProgressHUD, Bolts and more... And also used $(inherited) in the main project settings under "other linker flags". All done and working. Thanks for your help (;

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed finally to run my project after transferring a few frameworks and 3rd party's to Pod:
AWS, Parse, Facebook, SDWebImage, MBProgressHUD, Bolts and more...

And also added `$(inherited)` in the main project settings under "other linker flags". All done and working.

My Pod file looks like this:

> # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
>   platform :ios, ‘7.0’ # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift #
>   use_frameworks!
>
> target 'ProjectName' do
>
> source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
>
> pod 'AWSCore'
>
> pod 'AWSS3'
>
> pod 'Bolts'
>
> pod 'Parse'
>
> pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
>
> pod 'ParseCrashReporting'
>
> pod 'ParseUI'
>
> pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
>
> pod 'ParseTwitterUtils'
>
> pod 'SDWebImage'
>
> pod 'MBProgressHUD'
>
> end

Comment: Perfect  now you got it

Comment: I am working on it since 08:00 AM and now It is 01:30 AM ahhh good feeling that it is done, good night

Comment: Haha.  That's great. During first time i wasted my 3 days behind cocoa-pods issue and tried many solutions like you. Gn

Answer (score 0):

check your pod file if everything you need is in place, on your terminal run a `pod deintegrate` to de integrate your pod files, then pod `install` so you get a rest install, at least that worked for me after doing a lot of research without finding the right solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).